# ffpyplayer Image to QPixmap

Tags: python, pyqt

I am looking for a way to stream a video file to a QPixmap in PyQt using FfPyPlayer. The docs give an example to stream Image objects out of the player, however I am not sure how to convert this Image to a QPixmap. I do see that there is a way to convert it to a bytearray, and QPixmap does have a `QPixmap.loadFromData()` function but I was not able to tie these two together successfully.

Here's the example from the docs:

```
from ffpyplayer.player import MediaPlayer
import time

player = MediaPlayer(filename)
val = ''
while val != 'eof':
    frame, val = player.get_frame()
    if val != 'eof' and frame is not None:
        img, t = frame
        # Now what?!
```

EDIT
Well I did come up with a solution by converting the FfPyPlayer Image to a PIL Image and then a QPixmap via the Pillow `ImageQt.toqpixmap()` method. However I hesitate to mark this as an answer because it seems so inefficient that I would like to know if anyone else has a better solution.

```
from ffpyplayer.player import MediaPlayer
from PIL import ImageQt, Image

player = MediaPlayer(filename)
val = ''
while val != 'eof':
    frame, val = player.get_frame()
    if val != 'eof' and frame is not None:
        img, t = frame

        data = img.to_bytearray()[0]
        img2 = Image.frombytes("RGB", img.get_size(), bytes(data))

        pixmap = ImageQt.toqpixmap(img2) # <- returns a QPixmap
```

Comment: Have you tried to use QImage instead? You can get the QPixmap afterwards by using the static function [`QPixmap.fromImage(QImage)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#fromImage).

Comment: @musicamante What benefit would that be? Seems like it just ads another step...? Ideally I could convert the bytearray directly to a QPixmap (so I don't need to go via PIL) but I haven't been able to make that work.

Comment: QPixmap.loadFromData doesn't work well with "raw" image formats (which is what ffmpeg provides), and it uses QImage internally anyway, so there's no "another" step, actually. Try for example `QtGui.QImage(img.to_bytearray()[0], img.get_size()[0], img.get_size()[1], QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)`. In this case I'm assuming that the img.get_pixel_format() is "rgb24", you'll probably need to use a conversion from ffpyplayer [image format names](http://matham.github.io/ffpyplayer/tools.html#ffpyplayer.tools.pix_fmts) to those provided by [QImage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#Format-enum).

Comment: @musicamante That does work, and it is running realtime (24ps) on my system. Strange that QImage works with the raw data but not QPixmap. Anyway thanks for the help!

Comment: Good to know, now that we're certain that it works I'll add an answer about it, better explaining what's going on (I'm not able to upgrade to ffmpeg 3 so ffpyplayer can't be installed, and I didn't want to write one yet because of being impossible to test it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that QPixmap.loadFromData() expects actual image "files", while what ffpyplayer (as in ffmpeg) provides are actually raw images, which is the actual representation (rasterization) of the images as they will eventually appear.

For various reasons, QPixmap cannot directly deal with raw data, as it's intended for showing images on screen, while QImages can, as they also are hardware independent.

QImage can load raw image data (meaning that, for example, if the image is compressed, the raw data is the actual representation of an uncompressed image), but it needs to know something about the "image format" and, obviously the image width/height.
When you use QPixmap.loadFromData() what actually happens is that Qt "guesses" the image file format, decompresses it (if necessary) to get data about "each pixel", gets both graphical size and pixel format, then it builds an internal QImage with all that information and finally returns it as QPixmap.

In this case, you already have all that data provided by ffpyplayer, so you just skip the first "decoding" passage entirely and create a QImage, and then get a QPixmap from it.

```
while val != 'eof':
    frame, val = player.get_frame()
    if val != 'eof' and frame is not None:
        img, t = frame

        data = img.to_bytearray()[0]
        width, height = img.get_size()

        # the technical name for the 'rgb24' default pixel format is RGB888,
        # which is QImage.Format_RGB888 in the QImage format enum
        qimage = QtGui.QImage(data, width, height, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qimage)
```

Note that the default `out_fmt` of MediaPlayer is 'rgb24', I doubt you'll need to change it, but if you do avoid any YUV based pixel format, as QImage doesn't support them. It's still possible to convert it (there are [some methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Converting_between_Y%E2%80%B2UV_and_RGB)) but I'd not suggest to go that way at all.

Finally, consider the aspect ratio, which might change between the source image and what would be the actual representation (for example, anamorphic format). You can get that from `player.get_metadata()` and if it doesn't match the image aspect ratio, you can get the correct image with this:

```
pixmap = pixmap.scaled(targetWidth, targetHeight, 
    QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)
```

Comment: This works perfectly for most cases but when using  a strange aspect ratio I have issues. I.e. I am trying this with a video that has the dimensions 706 x 720 and am getting strange behavior (horizontal scanlines visible in the QPixmap, it is black and white and offset/distorted). Not sure if this is a problem with ffpyplayer itself or with Qt, any ideas?

Comment: @Spencer that seems a problem with the image format. Try to enforce `out_fmt=rgb24` when creating the MediaPlayer instance.

Comment: I didn't see that in the __init__ signature but I did see it as a method of the player, `MediaPlayer.set_output_pix_fmt('rgb24')` which unfortunately did not work. I've seen this problem before creating pixmaps from data with the incorrect format so I think you are right.

Comment: @Spencer try to run ffprobe on the video file and see the image format (it should be right after the format definition and before the resolution).

Comment: `yuv444p`. I generated this file as an h.264 mp4 using ffmpeg, if that helps.